# -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redhat

root@host [~]# **yum**

-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

**None- Actually, I deleted old python2.6 directory and install new python2.7 in linux redhat 4.4.7 OS.**

Comment: please help me....how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the system python; too many things rely on it (like your package manager!).  If you want to install a different version of Python, install it somewhere else (`/usr/local`, your home directory, etc).

If you actually deleted the `python2.6` *directory* (e.g., `/usr/lib/python2.6`), you haven't just deleted python 2.6 -- you have deleted *any additional python modules* that were installed on your system, potentially breaking all sorts of things.  There's not really a good way to recover from this situation.

If you were to restore the `/usr/lib/python2.6` directory from another system you would at least be able to run `yum` again, although your system would still be fundamentally broken.  Your best bet is to reinstall from scratch.

If you only deleted the `python2.6` *binary* and left the library directory intact, you could simply restore `/usr/bin/python2.6` and things would be relatively back to normal.

Comment: I think , i deleted additional python modules.thank you sir.

Comment: @larsks how do i re install the python from scratch without using yum ?

Comment: If you download the packages you can probably install them using the `rpm` command. For details on that process you probably want to post a question over at `superuser.com`, since it isn't really related to software development.