# Reinstall Python on CentOS after deleting default Python 2.7

Tags: python, bash, centos

I am using a Bluehost cloud server, which has `CentOs 6.10 (linux 2.6.32-754.14.2.e16.x86_64)`, I am trying to install python `3.7`, but somehow deleted python2.6 which is default in centOS (deleted from lib , lib64, bin ....).

Now when i try to use yum , its giving an error:

> `-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

**What should i do to reinstall python 2.6, so that yum will work?**

currently python 3.7.1 is working (`/root/python/Python-3.7.1/python`), but i cannot install pip or any other python packages such as numpy.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220813/bash-usr-bin-yum-usr-bin-python-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

> If you were to restore the /usr/lib/python2.6 directory from another
>   system you would at least be able to run yum again, although your
>   system would still be fundamentally broken. Your best bet is to
>   reinstall from scratch

Comment: Please just flag as duplicate instead of copy/pasting answers to very similar questions.

Comment: I flagged but thought I may as well include the important part of the answer here